# White flash when setImageWithUrl displays a cached image

Tags: ios, image, caching, afnetworking, afnetworking-2

Using AFNetworking 2.0's method setImageWithUrl, I set an image in an imageView located in a UITableViewCell. It works fine when the image displayed is first downloaded and then set. If, however, the image is available locally (has been cached) when it's set, there's a quick white flash before it is displayed.

Do you know how to avoid this?

Steps to reproduce:

1. Set image (image will be cached)
2. Close application
3. Start application
4. Set (the now cached) image

Code for setting the image:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    myCell *cell = (myCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"imageCell"];

    [cell.myImageView setImageWithURLRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:myImageUrl] placeholderImage:nil success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, UIImage *image) {
        cell.myImageView.image = image;

    } failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Failed");
    }];

    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
    return cell;  
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If anyone's bumping into the same issue, here's how I solved it:

In the success block, replace

```
cell.myImageView.image = image;
```

with

```
if (request) {
    [UIView transitionWithView:cell.myImageView
                      duration:0.8f
                       options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve
                    animations:^{[cell.myImageView setImage:image];}
                    completion:NULL];
}else{
    [cell.myImageView setImageWithURL:myImageURL];
}
```

Voilà, no more ugly flashes!

Credits to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14026483/2919327) for leading me to the right track.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your issue is related to cell reusing rather to the caching issue.

When your cells are reused (when scrolling the `UITableView` or reopening the app) they hold a reference to the old image. And when you pass `nil` to the `placeholderImage` parameter, AFNetworking does not resets your image. Here is the [source code](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/blob/master/UIKit%2BAFNetworking/UIImageView%2BAFNetworking.m#L138). So the new image is set in a `success` block. But this block may be called after a slight network delay making your image to flash. By the way, you may omit the success block so the AFNetworking will [set the image by itself](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/blob/master/UIKit%2BAFNetworking/UIImageView%2BAFNetworking.m#L151).

If you don't have a placeHolder image you should set the `myImageView.image` to `nil` before trying to set a new one asynchronously.

In addition you should check if the `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:` method returns a cell, and if not, create a new one. This may happen when the `UITableView` is created for the first time.

Here is an example:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    myCell *cell = (myCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"imageCell"];

    // Check if reused cell was returned.
    // If not create a new one, otherwise, reset the state of the reused cell
    if (!cell) {
        cell = [[myCell alloc] init];
    } else {
        cell.myImageView.image = nil;
    }

    [cell.myImageView
        setImageWithURLRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:myImageUrl]
        placeholderImage:nil
        success:nil
        failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
            NSLog(@"Failed");
        }];

    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

    return cell;  
}
```

Comment: Thank you for such an extensive and quick reply @smnh. Unfortunately, that didn't do the trick. I replaced my code with yours, but the flash still occurs. You might have pointed me in the right direction, though.

Comment: I tried setting a placeholderimage to see if the behaviour would change. Still a "flash"; the placeholder image is displayed for 0.X seconds before the cached image is is displayed. I guess I could try adding a fade effect.

Comment: Can it be that your `myImageView.backgroundColor` is set to white color? Or maybe there is a white view below the myImageView that flashes while the image is not set?

Comment: my background is indeed white. If curious of my solution/workaround, see my own answer. Thanks for your help!

Comment: You can set the background to be transparent `[UIColor clearColor]`, then the flash should not happen anymore. Another reason for that flash to occur is JPEG decompression delay, given that you are using white background and JPEG images for the `cellImage`.

Answer (score 0):

You need a function like this:

```
BOOL ImageDataHasPNGPreffix(NSData *data) {
NSUInteger pngSignatureLength = [kPNGSignatureData length];
if ([data length] >= pngSignatureLength) {
    if ([[data subdataWithRange:NSMakeRange(0, pngSignatureLength)] isEqualToData:kPNGSignatureData]) {
        return YES;
    }
}

return NO;
}
```

then when you save your data, you need to choose the right way to cache

```
//Saving data
if ([imageData length] >= [kPNGSignatureData length]) {
    imageIsPng = ImageDataHasPNGPreffix(imageData);
}

if (imageIsPng) {
    data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
}
else {
    data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, (CGFloat)1.0);
}
```